# How to enqueue Maps correctly?

Tags: php, wordpress, google-maps

I'm using the Root's theme - Sage

I'm trying to enqueue Google Maps, been at it for hours with no success.

I keep getting this error in Chrome's console:

```
Uncaught InvalidValueError: initMap is not a function ... js?key=MY_API_KEY&callback=initMap:95
```

From what I can work out, it means that it can't find the function like the classic jQuery undefined problem of script ordering.

setup.php

```
/**
 * Theme assets
 */

function assets() {
  wp_enqueue_style('sage/css', Assets\asset_path('styles/main.css'), false, null);

  wp_enqueue_style('font-awesome', '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css', false, null);

  if (is_single() && comments_open() && get_option('thread_comments')) {
    wp_enqueue_script('comment-reply');
  }
  wp_enqueue_script('sage/js', Assets\asset_path('scripts/main.js'), ['jquery'], null, true);

  wp_enqueue_script('jquery-validate', '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.15.1/jquery.validate.min.js', [], null, true);

  if (is_page_template('template-about.php')) {
    wp_enqueue_script('google-maps', '//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY_HERE&callback=initMap', [], null, true);
  }

}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', __NAMESPACE__ . '\\assets', 100);
```

Excerpt of my Main.js

```
(function($) {
  // Use this variable to set up the common and page specific functions. If you
  // rename this variable, you will also need to rename the namespace below.
  var Sage = {
    // All pages
    'common': {
          init: function() {

            if (!$('body').hasClass('home')) {
              $(this).find('.banner').removeClass('navbar-fixed-top');
            }

           var map;
           console.log('reached');

            function initMap() {
              var location = {lat: 51.47672559, lng: -3.17107379};
              var markerloc = {lat: 51.476852, lng: -3.167869};
              map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                 center: location,
                 scrollwheel: false,
                 zoom: 17
              });
              var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                 position: markerloc,
                 map: map,
                 title: 'Hello World!'
              });

          }
        }
          },
```

Line 106 is the googlemaps url line. Specifically the `&callback=initMap` part.

Scripts appear like this in the DOM.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY_HERE&#038;callback=initMap'></script>

<script type='text/javascript' src='//localhost:3000/app/themes/***********/dist/scripts/main.js'></script>
```

Can anyone help me out here?

I have been told this but I'm unsure on how to do it?

> Most likely what's happening here is that google-maps ends up enqueued
>   after sage/js. Your conditional block should account for that and add
>   google-maps as a dependency for sage/js.

Comment: initmap() is buried in `Sage` ... it's not accessible in global scope where you are setting the callback

Comment: Are you able to provide a solution as explanatory/demonstrative answer please?

Comment: quickest solution is take the map code out of Sage. beyond that you need to read up on javascript scope and closures

Comment: So, for example, moving initMap() to the very very top of the main.js file outisde the `(function($)` ? If so, I have done this and it doesn't fix the problem

Comment: then make your sage file a dependency of google maps in `wp_enqueue_script`

Comment: How would I do that? I have tried putting 'google-maps' in the square brackets on the sage/js line but it makes the script not load into the DOM

Comment: that's backwards ... read the `wp_enqueue_script` docs

Comment: If it's backwards then I'll switch it over.. docs don't tell me the answer.

Comment: sure they do ...they explain dependency

Comment: But not in my specific case in terms of ordering etc

Comment: dependency determines order...that's the whole point of it

Comment: Would have been more helpful if you could have provided a code example

Comment: I steered you through this and you want to now complain?? wow!

Comment: It's not a complaint but constructive criticism, lighten up!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As charlietfl stated about dependencies

```
wp_enqueue_script('google-maps', '//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY_HERE&callback=initMap', ['sage-js'], null, true);
```

I needed to add 'sage-js' as a dependency to maps.